# Allocate separate thread per event in FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, multithreading, filesystemwatcher

I am developing a windows service that contains the FileSystemWatcher. Once file creates, I have to make some network calls to a web API.

Please look at below code lines.

```
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler((object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) => { ProcessCreateEvent(e); });
```

Event handler

```
private async void ProcessCreateEvent(FileSystemEventArgs e){
      // make some network calls and do certain tasks
      // network calls doing asynchronously
}
```

I did in deep about the FileSystemWatcher and I understand that it is not the good practice to handle the network call in ProcessCreateEvent method. So how can I allocate the separate thread for each file change?

Comment: Why not simply start the Async Operation in the Event Handler? The same way you would start any synchronous code?

Comment: What's the question here exactly? You should be able to await your asynchronous methods in that event handler to take advantage of the TPL.

Comment: @JonathonChase It seems something happened while I posting the question. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Events already support `async`, so you can just do something like:

```
watcher.Created += this.ProcessCreateEvent;

private async void ProcessCreateEvent(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    var result = await asyncApi.GetStuffAsync();
}
```

You don't need to spin up another `Task` unless the non-async stuff you are doing in the event handler is expensive.

Comment: What should I do for non-async stuff in above method?

Comment: If the non-async stuff is fast then do it in the method body itself. If it is slow wrap it all in a `Task.Run` like in @Bob Dust's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can simply be done by making `ProcessCreateEvent` asynchronous like this:

```
    private async Task ProcessCreateEvent(FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // make some network calls and do certain tasks
        // network calls doing asynchronously
        await Task.Run(async () => {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:54522/api/values");
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        });
    }
```